# Adjust Margins in {res} while maintaining layout

Tags: margins, cv, resume

I am composing a resume based on the style file and example CV from "Latex template for creating a CV/Resume", which I found at http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Latex_template_creating_CV_.html.  Please note the style file there: res.cls.

I originally tried this code based on that CV:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}

\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
% if using pdflatex:
%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
%\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight} 


\begin{document}

\name{my name \vspace*{.1in}}

\begin{resume}
\section{\sc Contact Information}
\vspace{.05in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}p{2in}p{2in}}
x & y & z \\
x & y & z \\
x & y & z \\
\end{tabular}


\section{\sc Objective}
XYZ

\section{\sc Education}

{\bf XYZ}\\
\vspace*{-.15in}
\begin{itemize}
\item XYZ
\item XYZ
\item XYZ   
\end{itemize}


\section{\sc Section 1}
XYZ


\section{\sc Section 2}
XYZ

\vspace{.01in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3in}p{2.5in}}
X & Y \\
X & Y \\
X & Y \\
X & Y \\
\end{tabular}


\section{\sc Experience}
{\bf Job 1} \hfill {\bf Duration}
\begin{itemize}
\item XYZ
\begin{itemize}
\item XYZ
\end{itemize}
\item XYZ
\item XYZ
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-.1cm}
{\bf Job 2} \hfill {\bf Duration}
\begin{itemize}
\item Prose
\begin{itemize}
    \item Prose
    \item Prose
    \item Prose
    \item Prose
    \item Prose
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


%\vspace{-.1cm}
{\bf Job 3} \hfill {\bf Duration}
\begin{itemize}
\item XYZ
\item XYZ
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-.1cm}
{\bf Job 4} \hfill {\bf Duration}
\begin{itemize}
\item Prose
\begin{itemize}
    \item Prose
\end{itemize}
\item Prose
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-.1cm}
{\bf Job 5} \hfill {\bf Duration}
\begin{itemize}
\item XYZ
\item XYZ
\end{itemize}

\section{\sc Skills} 
\begin{itemize}
\item {\it \bf Technology}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item XYZ
        \item XYZ
    \end{itemize}
\item {\it \bf Languages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Prose
        \item Prose
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


\end{resume}
 \end{document}
```

I like the separate "column" ("column" might not be the correct terminology) for the section names.  However, the bottom margin is way too big.  So I added the following two lines so my code now began as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
```

But that change produced the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: No value specified for margin.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.992 \ProcessOptionsKV[c]{Gm}
                          %
?
```

So I changed the first line by adding  to be as follows and kept the rest the same:

```
\documentclass[margin=<value>,line]{res}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
```

This change does not keep the "left column" with headers that can be seen at this professor's CV: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/files/cv/paciorek-cv.pdf.  Instead, this change makes what used to be the "left column" part of the "column" that contains the rest of my resume.

So here are my questions: How can I make it so that I can make my margins 1 inch all around while maintaining that "left column"?  Do I have to change something in res.cls?  Would it be \topmargin (lines 775 and 780) in res.cls?  Or is there something I can change in my resume document?  Does it have something to do with these commented out lines of code (they were that way when I downloaded the .tex file), repeated from above:

```
% if using pdflatex:
%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
%\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
```

I should note that when I try to typeset res.cls on my computer after downloading it, I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:/FILE_EXTENSION/res.cls"
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \typeout
            {Document Style `res' <26 Sep 89>.}
?
```

Comment: Despite claims to the contrary, the class has not be properly updated for LaTeX2e! It still uses 20+ years obsolete font switches, for example, which ought not now be used in LaTeX documents at all. However, that is not responsible for your problem. The problem with the 'disappearing' column is that it is not a column. When you choose `margin` as a class option, section titles are set in the left margin. If that is too narrow, obviously the effect will not be what you might have hoped. You get errors when you try to compile the class because class files cannot generally be compiled.

Comment: That is, you cannot have 1in margins all round, use the `margin` class option and have section titles longer than 1in less whatever spacing you want to the left and right of the section title. Not without re-implementing the `margin` option in a completely different way. But then I think you are better off starting with a standard class. Major surgery on an outdated class designed for a very specific purpose is not generally terribly successful.

Comment: if you are using pdflatex uncomment the 2 lines. if you want to make the bottom smaller add `\textheight=10.0in` or `\textheight=what you see better`

Comment: @cfr Is there another package to construct resumes you recommend?  The resumes at "Using the LaTeX Resume Templates" (http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/) use {res}, and it sounds like I should stay away from {res}.

Comment: @touhami Nice fix!  When I do that, the top margin stays the same even though the bottom margin changes (i.e., 9.5in gives less room at the bottom than 10in, but the top margin stays the same.  I used \topmargin=-0.5 to get the desired top margin.  Why doesn't \textheight take into account the whole page?  Does it have to do with the {res} class or some other setting in my document?

Comment: the paperheight is divided into units =(1in+topmargin+headheight+headsep+topskip+textwidth+some (free) space) so `\textheight` can't control all these units. By defaul res.cls set topmargin=headheight=headsep=0pt

Comment: I just use a standard class and format it as I see fit. `moderncv` is popular but I don't know if it is any good.

Comment: @touhami Do you want to write down something answerlike?

Comment: @Johannes_B I am not sure now, may be later. If you can do it for me, thanks.